# how can I write this if-this-or-that more succinctly in php

Tags: php, refactoring

I have an if-statement with many options for true, and I have written it as below. How can I write this more succinctly?

```
foreach($data_array as $person){
    if(
    isset($person['dept']) && $person['dept'] == $list && $person['status'] == 'Current' ||
    isset($person['dept2']) && $person['dept2'] == $list && $person['status'] == 'Current' ||
    isset($person['dept3']) && $person['dept3'] == $list && $person['status'] == 'Current' ||
    isset($person['dept4']) && $person['dept4'] == $list && $person['status'] == 'Current' ||
    isset($person['dept5']) && $person['dept5'] == $list && $person['status'] == 'Current'
    )
{ // do something
```

Comment: Where has `$data_array` come from? If it's come from a database query, maybe a different query could remove the need for some of this.

Comment: Or maybe if the list of departments was an array instead of multiple separate properties this would be a lot simpler

Comment: And the `$person['status'] == 'Current'` part is always the same, so that clearly could be checked _once_ instead.

Comment: Why the "json" tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can write function to shorten your statements:

```php
function isValid(array $person, string $key, string $list): bool {
    return isset($person[$key]) && $person[$key] == $list;
}

foreach ($data_array as $person) {
    if (
        $person['status'] == 'Current'
        && (
            isValid($person, 'dept', $list)
            || isValid($person, 'dept2', $list)
            ...
        )
    )
}
```

---

*If* you could format your `$data_array` to be in following format:

```
[
    [
        'depts' => [
            'value1',
            'value2',
            ...
        ],
        'status' => 'Current'
    ],

    [
        'depts' => [
            'value3',
            'value4',
            ...
        ],
        'status' => 'Not Current'
    ]
]
```

then you could reduce code drastically to 2 conditions:

```php
foreach ($data_array as $person) {
    if ($person['status'] === 'Current' && in_array($list, $person['depts'])) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found simple enough way without needing additional functions or reformatting my data:

```
foreach($data_array as $person) {
    for ($i=""; $i<=5; $i++){ // starts with "" because the first department does not have a #
        if(
        isset($person['dept'.$i]) &&
        $person['dept'.$i] == $dept['id'] &&
        $person['status'] == 'Current'
        ){
    // do stuff
    }
}
```